# Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js

i need a solution to fix it
Every configuration of redis I have tested and it works fine, I use docker to run it
Am I using TusServer to upload files to the server

Comment: This question needs more detail. Are you using Docker Compose? Are you manually running different Docker containers? How is your application connected within you Docker environment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.